# Error: make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop

Tags: python, linux, opencv, virtual-machine, gnu

I am trying to install OpenCV on Linux on a VM and after running the following in the terminal I get the error from the title:

```
$ workon cv
$ cd ~/opencv
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \
    -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=~/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

I've looked up previously discussed topics and ./configure gives me "bash: ./configure: No such file or directory". Autoconf gives "autoconf: error: no input file".

What can I do to get around this problem?

Comment: Normally `cmake` should create a `Makefile` (or some other type of build/project file). Please check the output of the `cmake` command. If this doesn't help, show the output in your question. I suggest to change the title to something more specific, e.g. "OpenCV build - cmake fails with <error message>" or at least OpenCV build - cmake doesn't create Makefile"